# Coredata Crash: _PFObjectIDFastHash64

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

We have been facing a weird crash from core data from long time and haven't found anything what to do. Below is the crash stack to get more insight on it. It is a production issue and not replicate at our end.

```
Crashed: NSManagedObjectContext 0x2810fd450
0  CoreData                       0x6f8d8 _PFObjectIDFastHash64 + 40
1  CoreFoundation                 0xef54 __CFBasicHashRehash + 948
2  CoreFoundation                 0xe76c CFBasicHashRemoveValue + 2412
3  CoreFoundation                 0x45ce0 CFDictionaryRemoveValue + 336
4  CoreData                       0x10781c -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _forgetObject:propagateToObjectStore:removeFromRegistry:] + 132
5  CoreData                       0x29554 -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _processReferenceQueue:] + 916
6  CoreData                       0xa284c __90-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _registerAsyncReferenceCallback]_block_invoke + 80
7  CoreData                       0x1f754 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 156
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x4660 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
9  libdispatch.dylib              0xbde4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
10 libdispatch.dylib              0xc958 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x171a8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 656
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10f4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe94 start_wqthread + 8
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the problem could be in `NSManagedObjectContext` performing some work. Maybe integrating some data-collection lib, as Crashlytics can help.

Regarding stack trace: could you please send the original error message (as shown on screenshot)?[image: sample stack trace].

For now I can draw only bare suggestions that are not so relevant.

Comment: Is this really an answer, it looks more like a comment to me?

Comment: This is the main and original stack of crash which we got from crashlytics